# how to check if last message is equal to current message c#

Tags: c#, console-application

The title says it all. I want to make it so that the message is stored. The message is then sent(console.writeline), then the next time the method is called, an if statement will check if it is the same as the last message. something like this that actually works:

```
        static void SayMsg(string msg) {
            if (msg != oldmsg) {
                string oldmsg = msg;
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
```

so say if i called it twice, with the parameter "test" both times, it would only send once.

Comment: _oldmsg_ needs to maintain its value between calls. If you declare it inside the method then it is a local scoped variable and will loose its value when the scope ends. Declare it as static outside the method

Comment: The only way to do that is to remember some kind of state in a property outside the function.

Comment: Welcome. Can you let us know where exactly you're stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will need to store state between calls, so that's best modelled using a class with a field to store the state:

```
public sealed class MessageSender
{
    public void SayMsg(string msg)
    {
        if (msg == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(msg));

        if (msg == _lastMessage)
            return;

        _lastMessage = msg;
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    string? _lastMessage;
}
```

Then you'd need to create an instance of `MessageSender` where you need it, and call `SayMsg()` as required. Note that you would create only one instance of `MessageSender` and repeatedly call `SayMsg()` for it.

You would NOT create a new instance of it for each call to `SayMsg()` - obviously that wouldn't work because the `_lastMessage` state would be reset for each new instance of `MessageSender`.

Note: The `?` at the end of `string` above requires a newer version of C#. If it doesn't work for you, just remove it. (It tells the compiler that `_lastMessage` can be null.)